# How to get data from a table with blanks in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a table with some strings however there are some blank variables. So i cannot get specific rows after those blanks. My table looks like(hyphens are blank in real table):

a -  1 2 3 4 5 - 1 -

b 12 2 - - 3 7 - 2 g

c - - 12 - 2 - - - 1

So i want to put columns into lists like

list1=[1 2 -]

list2=[2 - 12]

list3=[3 - -]

list4=[5 7 -]

list5=[- - -]

Here's my code:

```
from astroquery.simbad import Simbad
import astropy.coordinates as coord
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
import pandas as pd
import astropy.units as u
from astropy import coordinates






column_names = ["#paper", "Object", "RA","Ra2","DEC","Dec2"]
data=pd.read_csv("jwebb.tsv", sep = '\t', names=column_names)

STARS=data.Object.to_list()
RA=data.RA.to_list()
DEC=data.DEC.to_list()
"""RA2=
DEC2="""
POS = [i+' '+k for i, k in zip(RA,DEC)]



customSimbad = Simbad()
customSimbad.add_votable_fields('flux(V)','flux(U)','flux(B)','flux(R)','flux(I)','flux(J)','flux(H)','flux(K)','flux(u)','flux(g)','flux(r)','flux(i)','flux(z)')
customSimbad.get_votable_fields()

onames=[]
mag1=[]
mag2=[]
mag3=[]
mag4=[]
mag5=[]
mag6=[]
mag7=[]
mag8=[]
mag9=[]
mag10=[]
mag11=[]
mag12=[]
mag13=[]



rad1='0.001s'
rad2='0.01s'
rad3='.1s'


for i in range(len(RA)):
        result_table = customSimbad.query_region(coord.SkyCoord(ra=RA[i], dec=DEC[i], unit=(u.hourangle, u.deg)), radius=rad1)
        if result_table is None:
            result_table = customSimbad.query_region(coord.SkyCoord(ra=RA[i], dec=DEC[i], unit=(u.hourangle, u.deg)), radius=rad2)
            if result_table is None:
                result_table = customSimbad.query_region(coord.SkyCoord(ra=RA[i], dec=DEC[i], unit=(u.hourangle, u.deg)), radius=rad3)
        if result_table is None:
            onames.append('none')
           
        else:    
            onames.append(result_table[0][:])
```

So i want to put specific columns into mag1, mag2, mag3.. etc. If there is no value on table i want to put 0 for that value into list.

Comment: Okay, so what happens when you use `data=pd.read_csv("jwebb.tsv", sep = '\t', names=column_names)`, and *how is that different* from what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Well if I understand, you show us:

```
a - 1 2 3 4 5 - 1 -

b 12 2 - - 3 7 - 2 g

c - - 12 - 2 - - - 1
```

Which is in fact:

```
a   1 2 3 4 5   1  

b 12 2     3 7   2 g

c     12   2       1
```

Then I would do:

```
data = 'a   1 2 3 4 5   1  \n\
b 12 2     3 7   2 g \n\
c     12   2       1 '

print (data) # Your raw space-separated data with empty fields as space.

print()

print(data.replace('  ', ' 0')) # Space-separated data with empty fiels as zero.
```

Output:

```
a   1 2 3 4 5   1  
b 12 2     3 7   2 g 
c     12   2       1 

a 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 0
b 12 2 0 0 3 7 0 2 g 
c 0 0 12 0 2 0 0 0 1
```

So the question remains: why do you have to deal with this? Just set a default value upstream in your process cause even though doing this may work it is quite bad practice.

Comment: Well, the simbad is getting some values to me. however, they are from a database and if there is not a value table has a blank when im trying to put them inside a list, i had some error. This is why im trying to get the blanks as 0

Comment: And so are you happy with my fix? It does it isn t it?

Comment: well i found totally different solution. I changed most of the code. But thanks for helping